# How is a Vector of Vector aligned in memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I understand as [Set size of vector of vectors at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087260/set-size-of-vector-of-vectors-at-run-time)
 describes, one can declare vector of vector as

```
vector<vector<int> > ref;
```

then resize the first level by

```
ref.resize(i);
```

and push element at the 2nd level:

```
ref[i].push_back(23);
```

But how are vector of vector aligned in memory?

For simple vector, it's a container and align its element continuously, like an `array`; but in the case of vector of vector, I couldn't see the picture.

As the size of each inner vector (the *vector* in vector of **vector**) size might change, does the outer vector of vector (the *vector* in **vector** of vector) align inner vectors continously? Does the outer vector researve memeory space for each inner vector? what if one vector overshoot?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The size of the `vector<int>` struct that is stored in `ref` is constant. Common implementations has this as three pointers, or around 12 bytes on 32-bit architectures, or 24 bytes on shiny new 64-bit architectures.

So `ref` manages roughly ref.capacity() * 12 bytes of continuous storage.

Each element/`vector<int>` in ref manages its own integers independent of the elements `ref` manages. In the artistic rendering below `ref.size() == ref.capacity()` for the sake of simplicity.

[image: Pretty picture]

So your

```
ref.resize(i);
```

only affects the top row. Your

```
ref[i].push_back(23);
```

only affects the i-th column.

Comment: *Common implementations has this at around 12 bytes.* => or 24 bytes on 64-bits architectures (which is more likely to be what the OP is toying with).

Answer (score 4):

```
vector<vector <int>> m;
```

1. The inner vector or rows are implemented as independent
   objects on the free store.
2. Elements in each row are *compactly* stored, capable of performing dynamic allocation through `push_back` and `resizing`.
3. It is not necessary for each inner vector in the `vector< vector<int> >` to have the same size. So, the inner-vectors (not their elements) are not stored contiguously. That means, the *first* element of `m[i]` is not stored in the address *immediately* next to the *last* element of `m[i-1]`.

> does the outer vector of vector (the vector in vector of vector) align inner vectors continously?

No. See point#2

> Does the outer vector researve memeory space for each inner vector?

No. See point#1. you need to `resize` or do `push_back` into inner vector.

> how are vector of vector aligned in memory?

```
vector<T> vec;
```

consumes this much memory

```
sizeof(vector<T>) + (vec.size() ∗ sizeof(T))
```

where,

`sizeof(vector<T>)` = 12 bytes

and `T` is `vector<int>` for a *vector of vector*.

So, the memory consumed for a 3-by-4 `vector<vector<int>>` would be.

```
 = sizeof(vector<vector<int>>) + (vec.size() * sizeof(vector<int>))
 = 12 + 3 * 12 
 = 48
```

> what if one vector overshoot?

[vector.resize function corrupting memory when size is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615518/vector-resize-function-corrupting-memory-when-size-is-too-large)

Answer (score 2):

A `vector<vector<int>>` could look like this in memory:

```
+-+-+-+
|b|e|c|  vector<vector<int>
+-+-+-+ 
 | | |
 | | +-------------------+
 | |                     |
 | +---------------+     |
 |                 |     |
 V                 V     V
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|b|e|c|b|e|c|b|e|c|  3x vector<int>
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ 
 | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | +-------------+
 | | | | | | | |               |
 | | | | | | | +-------+       |
 | | | | | | |         |       |
 | | | | | | V         V       V
 | | | | | |+-+-+-+-+-+      
 | | | | | ||i|i|i|i|i|   5x int   
 | | | | | |+-+-+-+-+-+      
 | | | | | |       
 | | | | +-+---+ 
 | | | |       | 
 | | | V       V 
 | | |+-+-+-+-+  
 | | ||i|i|i|i|  4x int
 | | |+-+-+-+-+
 | | |
 | +-+-----------+
 |               |
 V               V
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|i|i|i|i|i|i|i|i|  8x int
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Here `b` denotes the `begin()` poiner, `e` denotes the `end()` pointer and `c` denotes the `capacity()` pointer.

You see, that the *rows* are **not contiguous** in memory as you would expect from a matrix structure. Every vector (inner and outer vectors) takes care of it's own memory allocations. The outer vector does not care about what it's elements are doing.