# stl container of vectors of object c++

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl, containers

i have class with some vectors of objects, and also a lot of methods working on those vectors. So my pseudo-code looks like that:

```
method1(std::vector1);
method1(std::vector2);
.
.
.
method2(std::vector1);
method2(std::vector2);
.
.
.
(etc.)
```

Every time new vector of objects is being added to my class i have to remember to add new lines to all methods. So i'm started to thinking about new container that can store all that objects. I made a new class with a container that stores all my vectors of objects. Also all vectors where moved to that new class. I want to achieve possibility to add new vector to that class for each time i need a new one and iterate through all those vectors in all my methods, like that:

```
method1()
{
  for(auto& temp : container)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

And in my new class something like that:

```
vector<object>& getByIndex(size_t index) 
{
   return container[index]
}
```

I need to return that vector of object by reference because i need to do some operations on those objects. So... i'm asking what container should i use? And how it may be done? Maybe there is better solution. That's just idea that i've come up with. I was thinking about std::list because those vectors are changing theirs size, so there is a lot of reallocation. I don't want to kill my performance with std::vectorstd::vector<object>.

Also if list is okay than i need some help because I already tried with list :

```
std::vector<object>& getByIndex(size_t index)
{ 
    return (*std::next(m_container.begin(), index)); 
}
```

but it doesn't work. Methods that're using what i returned from getByIndex method as its argument, are not adding content to m_container. As if it is returned by value instead reference. Maybe i've made mistake with what i'm returning from that method? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: "Every time new vector of objects is being added to my class i have to remember to add new lines to all methods" is a definite [design smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_smell).

Comment: *I was thinking about std::list because those vectors are changing theirs size, so there is a lot of reallocation.* Even if the vectors change in size does not mean that the outer vector will need to reallocate. That will only happen when you add/remove from the outer vector itself.

Comment: Just use `std::vector<std::vector<Whatever>>`. Reallocations of the inner vectors won't affect the outer one.

Comment: @Quentin How is that? Correct me if I;m wrong but element of vectors needs to be contiguous isn't it? So if any of the inner vectors needs to reallocate than how it is possible that outer vector does not?

Comment: Each individual vector need to be continguous. That means that a vector does a dynamic allocation to it's own contoguous memory block. So the outer vector will not have all the inner vectors data in contiguous memory, it will have the inner vector objects in contigous memory. The data in the inner vectors are stored in separate blocks allocated by each vector.

Comment: @super okay, thanks a lot

Comment: A vector consists of 3 pointer. Begin, end and reserved size of memory. If you add stuff to one vector it just changes the value of these pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container you are looking for is `std::vector`.

> I was thinking about std::list because those vectors are changing theirs size, so there is a lot of reallocation.

A `std::vector` does not change its size when you add elements. `std::vector::size()` returns the number of elements, but `sizeof(some_vector)` is constant. A extremely simplified model of `std::vector` that should be sufficient to understand why is:

```
template <typename T>
struct fake_vector {
    T* data;
    // ... other stuff ...
};
```

It doesn't matter if `data` points to an array with 10 elements, 42, or 10000 elements, the size of the vector object is always the same.

In general instances of a given type always have the same size. Thats why you can have arrays of objects.

For the last part of the question you would need to show a complete example, but with a vector of vectors, that method would simply be:

```
std::vector<object>& getByIndex(size_t index)
{ 
    return data[index];
}
```

Often a flat `std::vector<T>` is better than a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` because the big plus of `std::vector` is its data locality (elements are stored in contiguous memory), and because a `std::vector` adds a level of indirection this data locality is lost in nested vectors (only the inner vectors elements are stored in contiguous memory). However, if you are only working on the inner vectors, then that may not be a real disadvantage.

Comment: I have with considerable effort and immeasurable talent illustrated how a  vector of vectors is laid out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499774/451600.

Comment: @Captain that is indeed an impressive piece of art. Some colors would be awesome, but maybe I am too demanding

Comment: @idclev 463035818 Everything is clear now. But i'm not really get what you said about using templates -> "(...) because the big plus (...)". I know what templates are but it just didn't click for me with that what you said here. Everything beside that is perfectly clear.

Comment: @Tojmak i didnt say anything about templates. The last part is about the memory layout of a nested vector. Look at the link in the first comment for more details. A nested vector is not that different from a list. The elements of the inner vectors are stored contiguously, also the inner vectors are stored contiguously in the outer vector. But the elements are not stored direclty in the vector, for example with `std::vector<std::vector<T>> x;` the elements of `x[0]` are stored in memory not necessarily close to the memory where elements of `x[1]` are stored

Comment: @idclev 463035818 oh, okay, sorry, T was missleading for me as usually i see that with templates. Thanks a lot for help.